# Remove single item in Kendo UI Grid using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI Grid on a site with AngularJs. How can I update/add/delete one single array item inside a the DataSource and have the Grid update without refreshing the entire grid?

If I try just replacing the DataSource object, the grid sure enough updates, but all grouping, column ordering and sorting gets reset.

**Update #1 - Persistent Scroll Position**

I achieved this by reading this post: http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-grid-how-to-keep-scoll-position-after-calling-sync-(with-batch-property-set-to-true) ending up with this code:

```js
$scope.activityGridOptions = {
  scrollable: true,
  dataBound: function(e) {
    restoreScrollState();
  },
  dataBinding: function(e) {
    saveScrollState();
  }
  // ...
}

function saveScrollState() {
  $("#kendogrid .k-grid-content").scroll(function () {
    webStorage.local.add("gridScrollTop", $(this).scrollTop());
    webStorage.local.add("gridScrollLeft", $(this).scrollLeft());
  });
}

function restoreScrollState() {
  // Restore scroll state
  $("#kendogrid .k-grid-content").scrollTop(webStorage.local.get("gridScrollTop"));
  $("#kendogrid .k-grid-content").scrollLeft(webStorage.local.get("gridScrollLeft"));
}
```

**Update #2: Angular ui-grid**

After struggeling with Kendo UI Grid for two weeks, I finally abandonned the entire framework yesterday evening. Then I picked one of the top other Grids - and ended up with [Angular ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/) which I was able to program to replace Kendo UI Grid after about 7 hours of work.

I am not saying Kendo UI is bad software, but to me it doesn't seem to speak Angular well. At least not with my specific requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataSource exposes the following methods you can use:
- [add](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-add)
- [at](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-at)
- [get](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-get)
- [insert](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-insert)
- [remove](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-remove)

With these you can update/add/delete items in the DataSource without replacing it entirely.
All of these methods set the DataSource as "dirty" so the UI is automatically updated.

Comment: Thank you. Seems to work fine. What would be the best way to replace an item? Delete and re-add? Or is there any way to replace the data inside the row after running an .at(...)? 

I tried replacing one of the attributes of the object yielded by .at() and then setting dirty to true. It worked - but is that the way to go about?

Comment: `remove` and then `insert` is the way to go if you cannot make sure you remove/replace all "old" data on an object returned by `at`.

Comment: Thank you Sergui. I tried both removing/re-adding and using Underscore's extend method to pass updated attributes to the updated item (and setting item to dirty), but both methods make the scrollbars reset, collapsed groups to open and reordered columns to reset. I want the row to update without the UI resetting. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Unfortunately KendoUI does not persist scrolling position itself. You might find this useful: http://www.telerik.com/forums/data-source-update-resets-grid-scollbar

Comment: Yes, I found and implemented that one myself. So now the scroll position is persistent. I am currently trying to make column visibility, width, filtering and grouping persistent. Am I correct that this is the only way to achieve persistence on columns, grouping and filtering? http://jsbin.com/anisip/1/edit?js,output --- also, I am wondering if I am really approaching this the right way. There must be loads of implementations where AngularJs is updating/adding/deleting single rows in a grid via the dataSource and still maintaining the filtering/grouping/ordering/resizing of columns?

Comment: Yes, but not with KendoUI :)

Comment: Interesting :-) Could I ask which approach they would use? (which grid component?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76032/discussion-between-nitech-and-sergiu-paraschiv).